# define property in code behind and reference it in ASCX file

Tags: c#, properties, code-behind, episerver

```
public List<string> Test1
{
    get
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
        {
            "a",
            "minie",
            "lilo"
        };

       return list1;
    }
}
```

Can anybody advise what's wrong with this piece of code? I have this in the code behind file and in the ascx I am trying to render it like this: `<%= Test1[0] %>` but it doesn't work (no errors, but the ascx is not rendered where I put it, for editing purposes). I work this in correlation with episerver 6, e.g. the ascx is not rendered in the layout block where it's supposed to. As soon as I drop the `<%= Test1[0] %>`, the block becomes visible. I need a way to reference the Test1 list (or the first element for starters).

Comment: How is it supposed to render? It's a list of strings - how should that be represented in the web page?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you compile your project after you've added the list in code-behind? I see nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score -1):

You're not really doing anything with your list by just putting it there. Render it:

```
<% foreach(string s in Test1) { %>
    <div><%:s%></div>
<% } %>
```